# Ambiguous use of 'dismiss()' on UIButton when converting to swift 3.0

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, swift2

I have programmatically created an UIButton in swift 2.0 named `noBtn`, which signifies the dismissal of an `UIViewController`. When the user clicks the button, the view controller containing the button dismisses. When I converted to swift 3.0 I kept getting this error:

- Ambiguous use of 'dismiss()'

I tried adding arguments to `dismiss()` but it didn't work. Here is my original code without the arguments.

```
noBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(SetUpNameViewController.dismiss), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
```

Comment: Update your question with your `dismiss` method.

Comment: The dismiss method is part of the Swift library

Comment: its a method that is built in, it worked in swift 2.0 but in swift 3.0 it doesnt

Comment: There is no built-in method called `dismiss`. And that is what the error message is telling you.

Comment: Oke, then it was in swift 2.0 and they took it out in swift 3.0

Comment: What you were doing was never right.

Comment: Ok I'm an idiot. It was a method I created and the name of the class was setupnameviewxonteoller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rewrite like this. First, give the same class a `dismiss` method:

```
func dismiss() {
    self.dismiss(animated:true)
}
```

Second, change your `selector` to `#selector(dismiss)`.

Now your selector will call your `dismiss` function which will call `dismiss(animated:completion:)` which is what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Swift 2

```
dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
```

Swift 3

```
dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```